# Type-dependency between function arguments with function overloads in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a factory function, which takes a type argument to indicate the type of object to create, plus an parameter argument with parameters describing the object, which is dependent on the type of the object. A simplified example would look like this:

```js
enum EntityType {
  TABLE,
  BUCKET
}
type TableParams = { tableName: string }
type BucketParams = { bucketName: string }

function createEntity (type: EntityType.TABLE, params: TableParams): void
function createEntity (type: EntityType.BUCKET, params: BucketParams): void
function createEntity (type: EntityType, params: TableParams | BucketParams): void {
  switch(type) {
    case EntityType.TABLE:
      console.log('table name:', params.tableName)
      break
    case EntityType.BUCKET:
      console.log('bucket name:', params.bucketName)
      break
  }
}
```

The function overloads ensure that users can only call the function with the right kind of parameters, depending on the entity type, e.g.

```js
createEntity(EntityType.TABLE, { tableName: 'foo' })
createEntity(EntityType.BUCKET, { bucketName: 'bar' })
createEntity(EntityType.BUCKET, { tableName: 'fox' }) // => No overload matches this call.
```

The first two calls works just fine, but the 3rd call causes a compilation error: "No overload matches this call".

But how do I ensure type-safety *inside* the function? I.e. the example above doesn't actually compile because "Property 'tableName' does not exist on type 'TableParams | BucketParams'."

Shouldn't TypeScript be able to deduce the type of the `params` argument, based on which of the 2 function overloads matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of needding the enum and not using a typeguard by putting all params inside of one interface type.

```
interface EntityData {
    type: { new( ...args : any ) : BaseEntity };
    // Add shared member params
}

interface TableData extends EntityData {
    type: typeof TableEntity;
    tableName: string;
}

interface BucketData extends EntityData {
    type: typeof BucketEntity;
    bucketName: string;
}

class BaseEntity {
    constructor( data : EntityData ) {
        //assign any shared member params here
    }
}

class TableEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public tableName : string;

    constructor( data : TableData ) {
        super(data);
        this.tableName = data.tableName;
        console.log('table name:',this.tableName);
    }
}

class BucketEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public bucketName : string;

    constructor( data : BucketData ) {
        super(data);
        this.bucketName = data.bucketName;
        console.log('bucket name:', params.bucketName);
    }
}

function createEntity( data: TableData ): BaseEntity | undefined;
function createEntity( data: BucketData ): BaseEntity | undefined;
function createEntity( data: EntityData ): BaseEntity | undefined {
    if ( data ) {
        return new data.type(data );
    }
    return undefined;
}

createEntity( { type : TableEntity, tableName : 'foo'});
```

You can make the above more type safe by using it this way

```
let myTableData : TableData = { 
    type: TableEntity,
    tableName : 'foo'
}

createEntity( myTableData );

// The above will compile
// The below 2 example will give compile errors

let myTableData2 : TableData = { 
    type: BucketEntity,
    tableName : 'foo'
} // Will give type error for BucketEntity here

let myTableData3 : TableData = {
    type: TableEntity,
    bucketName : 'foo'
}  // Will give error here for bucketName not existing in TableData
```

If you still want the overloads I would use a typeguard inside of the switch so it is properly typed

```
enum EntityType {
  TABLE,
  BUCKET
}
type TableParams = { tableName: string }
type BucketParams = { bucketName: string }

function createEntity (type: EntityType.TABLE, params: TableParams): void
function createEntity (type: EntityType.BUCKET, params: BucketParams): void
function createEntity (type: EntityType, params: TableParams | BucketParams): void {
  switch(type) {
    case EntityType.TABLE:
        if( paramsAreTableParams( params ) ) {
            console.log('table name:', params.tableName);
        } else {
            console.log('incorrect params');
        }
        break;
    case EntityType.BUCKET:
        if( paramsAreBucketParams( params ) ) {
            console.log('table name:', params.bucketName);
        } else {
            console.log('incorrect params');
        }
        break;
  }
}

function paramsAreTableParams( params : TableParams | BucketParams ) : params is TableParams {
    return ( params as TableParams).tableName != undefined;
}

function paramsAreBucketParams( params : TableParams | BucketParams ) : params is BucketParams {
    return ( params as BucketParams).bucketName != undefined;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how I would call the `createEntity` function in the first code sample.   Something like `createEntity({ type: TableEntity, tableName: 'foo' })` doesn't work: "Argument of type '{ type: typeof TableEntity; tableName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EntityData'."

Comment: Sorry fixed I guess you will still need to overrides unless you wanted any type but the first part will allow you to not use if's and switches inside the function

Comment: Ok, I get the gist of it and I will play around with your idea some more. As is, your code is not truly type-safe yet, as e.g. `createEntity({ type : BucketEntity, tableName : 'foo'})` is accepted by the compiler and produces the output `bucket name: undefined`.

Comment: I updated the above answer a bit

Comment: Thank you, @derek-lawrence! Using the entity constructor as the type property on the data interface is a really neat trick. Your updated solution now works beautifully.